# How do I send a redirect request when some one creates a reverse proxy for my site on his site ?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, http-redirect

In apache or by any other means, one can proxy to my website, thereby displaying my entire content in his URL.

For example in apache2, configuration with following lines

```
ProxyPass / http://myawesomewebsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myawesomewebsite.com/
```

He (bad guy) serves all my contents as if it is his. How do I prevent it. I believe I need to send a redirect request, but on what basis, and what configuration would be required to do that. Currently I have the following. I noticed, Google does it and so does Facebook and everyone else does that.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.myawesomewebsite.com

    ServerAdmin me@myawesomewebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthCecker.*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myawesomewebsite\.com
    RewriteRule . https://www.myawesomewebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass /biz/ http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /biz/ http://localhost:8080/

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.12/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.12/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a redirect by checking the HOST name in the configuration. Following is the configuration used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myawesomewebsite.com
    ServerAdmin me@myawesomewebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.myawesomewebsite\.com$ [OR] [NC]
    RewriteCond     %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)$   https://www.myawesomewebsite.com$1   [R=301,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPass /biz/ http://10.0.0.12:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /biz/ http://10.0.0.12:8080/

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.12/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.12/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, with further I found that I can even display google page - including search results on my website with following configuration - after enabling ssl `a2enmod ssl`, and ommitting `ProxyPreserveHost On`.

```
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.awesomewebsite\.com$ [OR] [NC]
RewriteCond     %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$   https://www.awesomewebsite.com$1   [R=301,L]
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPass / http://www.google.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.com/
```

I guess, if Google haven't done it yet, I shouldn't be worried about this. However I do know about the implications it could have. Can anyone enlighten me on what kind of risks this could have ?

Thanks.